# include 4 images as different panels in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to include 4 already present images into one new image, done and created in matlab, like a collage, with 4 images present adjacent to each other, bordering, in the new image. I really do not know where to start. Could you please help me here? In matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, apart from What Hassan suggested, I was able to achieve my purpose easily using subplot and subimages. 
Eg.

```
    subplot(2,2,1)
    imshow(I1)
    subplot(2,2,2)
    imshow(I2)
```

Thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

Another options if you don't want white space between images is to combine the images into a single matrix.

ie:

```
image([I1 I2; I3 I4])
```

of course the images have to be the same size for this to work...